# Chrome Extension Using Manifest 3 and Multiple Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am trying to import scripts and am apparently only able to get one. I am using this manifest:

```
{
   "manifest_version": 3,

   "name": "Auto_Select",
   "description": "This extension auto selects Mturk HITs",
   "version": "1.0",

   "action": {
      "default_icon": "auto_select.png",
      "type": "module",
      "default_popup": "auto_select.html"
  },
  "background": {
      "service_worker": "worker_wrapper.js"
  },
  "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "activeTab"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
      "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

This is "worker_wrapper.js":

```
try {
   importScripts("js.cookie.js", "auto_select.js", "cookie_mgmt.js");
} catch(e) {
   console.log(e);
}
```

When I try to load the extension I get this error:

ReferenceError: document is not defined
at auto_select.js:26:1
at worker_wrapper.js:4:5

All the scripts are in the root directory for the extension so I don't understand why it doesn't error on  the first script but rather on the 2nd. Can someone help me with this? TIA.

Comment: The service worker has no access to the document functions - you should perhaps try marking your worker as a module and importing your other scripts as modules

Comment: The error message says that `document` is not defined. You can't use these scripts in a service worker. You'll need to use a different solution depending on what exactly those scripts do e.g. chrome.cookies API may help.

Comment: Ugh! Both of the last 2 scripts use document to access html elements and add listeners since inline scripts are also not allowed. Is there some other way to do that?

Comment: It depends on the goal. What you do currently doesn't do anything useful because service worker has no relation to documents.